# Express.js sometiomes returns Cannot GET /

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What I'm trying to achieve is that when I access `http://localhost:3000/app` it displays `myFile.html` and when I access `http://localhost:3000/api` it returns `"It worked!"`.

So far I have these two files:

App.js:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("./"));

app.get("/app", (request, response) => {
    fs.readFile("./myFile.html", "utf8", (err, html) => {
        if (err) {
            response.status(500).send("A problem occured" + err);
        }
        response.send(html);
    })
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log("App available on http://localhost:3000"));
```

server.js:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("./"));

app.get("/api", (request, response) => {
    response.send("It worked!");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log("App available on http://localhost:3000"));
```

The problem is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't - I get the `Cannot GET /app` or `Cannot GET /api` errors respectively. I've determined that when I run `node App.js` and `node server.js` then the one which I run last works excpected... But sometimes they both work. I know that this is very confusing, but I can't really figured out when exactly it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run two servers on the same port.  And *each URL* doesn't need to be *its own entire server*.

Include both endpoints in *one* server:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("./"));

// one URL endpoint
app.get("/app", (request, response) => {
    fs.readFile("./myFile.html", "utf8", (err, html) => {
        if (err) {
            response.status(500).send("A problem occured" + err);
        }
        response.send(html);
    })
});

// another URL endpoint
app.get("/api", (request, response) => {
    response.send("It worked!");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log("App available on http://localhost:3000"));
```

Alternatively, if you *do* want them to be separate servers, they need to run on separate ports.  (Or they can run on the same port on separate computers.)